# Ascii controls in php

Tags: php, ascii

I am trying to send a string with ascii controls but it is not working what am I doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
      <?php
     $str = chr(5);
$str2 = chr(2);
$str3 = chr(3);
echo $xml_data = '<$str><$str2> XX.XXXX
<SGREQ>
    <A1>123456789</A1>
    <A2>123456789</A2>
    <A4><B1>12345</B1></A4>
    <A10>1</A10>
</SGREQ> <$str3>';



$URL = "https://abc.def.com:123456";

                $ch = curl_init($URL);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                            'Content-Type: text/xml',   
                                            'Connection: Keep-Alive',
                                           'Content-length: ' . 
 ?>
```

I need the string to be sent as

```
 $xml_data= <ENQ><STX>XX.XXXX<SGREQ>
    <A1>123456789</A1>
    <A2>123456789</A2>
    <A4><B1>12345</B1></A4>
    <A10>1</A10>
</SGREQ> <ETX><CAN>';
```

My code sends it as 
   $xml_data= XX.XXXXXX 123456789 123456789 12345 1

it is missing the tags and the ascii controls.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: your `$str`, `$str2` and `$str3` won't be replaced by values, because you use single quotes.

Comment: The tags aren't missing, your browser just tries to render them as HTML and that's why you don't see them.

Comment: So should I use double quotes like "$str, str2, xx.xxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

use double quote for var replacing

```
echo $xml_data = "<$str><$str2> XX.XXXX
  <SGREQ>
    <A1>123456789</A1>
    <A2>123456789</A2>
    <A4><B1>12345</B1></A4>
    <A10>1</A10>
   </SGREQ> <$str3>";
```

and check the result with and editor and not in the browser result (the browser don't show the tag) .

if you see the source code eg with firefox with ctrl+U you see the entire code

Answer (score 0):

You may switch to double quotes as suggested by scaisEdge, or as an alternative, use the php heredoc syntax.

```
echo $xml_data = <<<XML
<$str><$str2> XX.XXXX
<SGREQ>
    <A1>123456789</A1>
    <A2>123456789</A2>
    <A4><B1>12345</B1></A4>
    <A10>1</A10>
</SGREQ> <$str3>
XML;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Actually I need to send the string like this  $xml_data= ascii XX.XXXX<SGREQ>
    <A1>123456789</A1>
    <A2>123456789</A2>
    <A4><B1>12345</B1></A4>
    <A10>1</A10>
</SGREQ> ascii; with no brackets the STX control in front of the string and ETX control after the string.

Comment: The heredoc opening and closing identifiers  `<<<XML` and `XML;` will not be a part of the string. Hence, will not be transmitted along with your XML. Everything that fall in between is yours to modify as you see fit. ;)